# Interface multiple I2C slaves to microcontroller

Tags: i2c

I want to communicate the Tiva C ARM Cortex M4 to sensorhub from TI which has multiple sensors with different I2C addresses such as MPU9150, BMP180, Temperature Sensors...
With a single I2C slave, i can communicate to it successfully, but if my project involves interface Microcontroller with both MPU9150 and BMP180, then i get stuck.
Anybody suggest me the process of commnunication in this case?

Comment: You have to change the address of the slave, which is expected to send data. 
the right call should be: 
I2CMasterSlaveAddrSet(I2C0_BASE, SLAVE_ADDRESS, true);
And then just let the master lissten, if anything is sent

Comment: Then it should be like this?
loop{  
     I2CMasterSlaveAddrSet(I2C0_BASE, SLAVE_ADDRESS_1, true);  
     ReadData_1();    
     I2CMasterSlaveAddrSet(I2C0_BASE, SLAVE_ADDRESS_2, true);  
     ReadData_2();  
}

Comment: I guess so, yes!

Comment: @TuyenVoQuang You should copy that comment into an answer so we can upvote it.